# javascript get value of radio button not selected

Tags: javascript

Perhaps a stupid question, perhaps because im a javascript rookie but lets say I have **multiple groups of radio buttons with 2 or 3 radio buttons per group.**

I can easily get rad1(if selected) by

```
if (radios[i].checked) {
            myradiovalue=radios[i].value
}
```

But now how will I get value of rad2 which is not clicked

Comment: Radio Buttons should have a default value that is set. What is the need of getting the value of a Radio Button if the user hasn't gave his input?

If the user tried to submit the form with a unchecked Radio Button throw an error for the user.

Comment: @EricE because I want to display the radio button not clicked in a string for confirmation, or is that bad logic

Comment: `$("input[name=setName]:not(:checked)")`

Comment: @dandavis thank you that was kind of the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine if the radio button's checked attribute is false and then set the value

```
if (radios[i].checked == false) {
    myradiovalue = radios[i].value
}
```

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to check

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!radios[i].checked) {
    myradiovalue=radios[i].value
}
```